# pipe2(...) vs pipe() + fcntl(...), why different?

Tags: c, sockets, pipe, nonblocking

I'm trying to build a redistributable binary to put on an old NAS that only has glibc 2.3.  So [`pipe2()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) isn't available on that machine, but the code I'm trying to build has the following line:

```
if (pipe2(info_pipe, O_CLOEXEC | O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
    goto info_pipe_err;
```

My understanding is that the reason `pipe2()` exists is to avoid race conditions by taking the `O_CLOEXEC | O_NONBLOCK` at the time of opening vs. doing it in two steps.  But there are no threads in the case I'm looking at, so I thought I might just substitute in:

```
if (pipe(info_pipe) < 0)
    goto info_pipe_err;

int direction; // 0=READ, 1=WRITE
for (direction = 0; direction < 2; ++direction) {
    int oldflags;
    oldflags = fcntl(info_pipe[direction], F_GETFL);

    if (oldflags < 0)
        goto info_pipe_err;

    if (fcntl(info_pipe[direction], 
        F_SETFL, oldflags | O_NONBLOCK | O_CLOEXEC) < 0)
        goto info_pipe_err;
}
```

But it's seemingly not interchangeable, because the code isn't working.  Why isn't this equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Answering my own question because I figured it out, just posting here for posterity.)*

If you're building a binary on a newer compiler for an older system, that runtime probably doesn't know the value for `O_CLOEXEC` as that flag was introduced with `pipe2()`.  If it knows anything, it knows `FD_CLOEXEC`.  And you don't set that using `F_SETFL`, you use `F_SETFD` which is a separate `fcntl()` call.

The following substitution should work:

```
if (pipe(info_pipe) < 0)
    goto info_pipe_err;

int direction; // 0=READ, 1=WRITE
for (direction = 0; direction < 2; ++direction) {
    int oldflags;
    oldflags = fcntl(info_pipe[direction], F_GETFL);

    if (oldflags < 0)
        goto info_pipe_err;

    if (fcntl(info_pipe[direction],
        F_SETFL, oldflags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
        goto info_pipe_err;

    oldflags = fcntl(info_pipe[direction], F_GETFD);
    if (oldflags < 0)
        goto info_pipe_err;

    if (fcntl(info_pipe[direction],
        F_SETFD, oldflags | FD_CLOEXEC) < 0)
        goto info_pipe_err;
}
```

As noted, this does not have the thread-safety aspect offered by `pipe2()` allowing all this to be done at once.